# Progress Bar formula to get to 100% after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have this code in a method and the method i call it in a timer1 tick event that it's interval set to 1000ms.

```
counter += 1;
progressBar1.Value = counter * 10;
label9.Text = counter.ToString();
label9.Visible = true;
if (counter == 10)
```

Now it's updating every 10 seconds so it's working good the progressBar value is jump each 10% untill 100%.
Buw now i want to change and check for 60 seocnds:

```
if (counter == 60)
```

Now what the progressBar1.Value should be ?

```
progressBar1.Value = counter * 10;
```

Instead * 10 what it should be ?

Comment: `100/60` could it really be that simple? yes it could. Might have to convert it to an int after the division

Comment: progressBar1.Value += (double)100/(double)60; (after setting progressBar1.Maximum to 10)

Comment: The math really is stunningly simple. If you want your progress bar to go from 0 to 100 in 60 seconds, then each second you would increase the value by 100/60. Or, since your `counter` value is incrementing by 1 each second, the value is `counter * 100/60`. That said, adjusting the progress bar control's maximum value to 60 is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`Maximum` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `ProgressBar`:

> Gets or sets the maximum value of the range of the control. The default is 100.

So in your original code, you could do:

```
p.Maximum = 10;

counter += 1;
progressBar1.Value = counter;
label9.Text = counter.ToString();
label9.Visible = true;

if (counter == 10)
```

And in your updated code, change the `Maximum` to 60 and keep (almost) everything else the same:

```
p.Maximum = 60;

counter += 1;
progressBar1.Value = counter;
label9.Text = counter.ToString();
label9.Visible = true;

if (counter == 60)
```